# ¿Qué lenguaje debo usar en Windows para crear un script que instale paquetes o dependencias de Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, dependencias

Yo estoy haciendo un Software con Python 3 y ese Software necesita dependencias(paquetes) de Python para ser ejecutado, entonces quiero hacer un script que instale esos paquetes si el usuario que ejecuta el programa no lo tiene instalado, osea si no tiene instalado Python 3 que lo instale, que si no tiene un paquete de Python nesesario que también lo instale.

No se si esto se pueda hacer con Python, intente con Bash pero en Visual Studio Code no ejecuta el código y no sé si el lenguaje Bash pueda trabajar con pip para instalar paquetes de Python, por último no sé si está pregunta ya a sido respondidas, aparecieron preguntas relacionadas pero no lo que busco hacer, la verdad desconozco de cómo hacer esto, entonces no sé cómo hacer la busca bien.

Comment: No lo he usado nunca, pero quizás pyinstaller sea lo que necesitas

Comment: Yo si he usado `pyinstaller` pero yo siempre he tenido las dependencias instaladas, entonces voy a programar una parte del código ahora y voy a desinstalar el paquete, luego lo convierto en un EXE con pyinstaller a ver si instala las dependencias y en un rato escribo a ver.

Comment: Nada amigo, al convertirlo a .EXE no instala los módulos :(.

Comment: ¿Y cuál sería el problema? ¿distribuir tu aplicativo? Si necesitas una aplicación *nativa* entonces usa herramientas y lenguajes adecuados. Siempre que se distribuye una aplicación se necesitan dependencias y que se cumplan requisitos mínimos. Hay soluciones para todo, la mayoría de pago, pero siempre habrá un requerimiento o dependencia previa, es algo que el usuario final debe asumir. Saludos

Comment: Ya lo solucione, simplemente a la hora de convertir el archivo de .py a .exe yo debo de tener las librerías que usa el Software instaladas, así cuando convierta el archivo de Python en un archivo ejecutable(EXE) las librerías necesarias se empaqueten, yo estaba haciendo lo contrario, probaba primero desinstalando las librerías y después convertía el archivo a un .exe y no era así, debo de tener las librerías yo instaladas para que se empaqueten en el ejecutable, cuando probé esto, por ultimo probé desinstalando las librerías, luego volví a ejecutar el EXE  y el Software funciono sin problemas.